# Sinalizar ambiente ao enviar e-mail para usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.
Cada formulário que é cadastrado em meu sistema ele envia em e-mail para algumas pessoas avisando que foi cadastrado, só que eu tenhos dois ambientes, um de homologação e um de produção.
Preciso que quando enviar um email, ele sinalize o lugar que foi cadastrado

```
public void NovoEventoAdverso(int patientId, int hospitalId, int usuarioId)
        {
            var cadastroRepository = new CadastroRepository();
            var investigadorRepository = new UsuarioRepository();
            var randomizacaoRepository = new RandomizacaoRepository();

            var paciente = cadastroRepository.GetByPatientId(patientId, hospitalId);
            var investigador = investigadorRepository.GetbyId(usuarioId);
            var randomizacao = randomizacaoRepository.GetByPatientId(patientId, hospitalId);

            MailMessage objEmail = FactoryMailMessage();

            objEmail.To.Add("Nome Teste <teste@teste.com.br>");

            objEmail.Subject = $"Novo Evento Adverso - {paciente.inpac}";

            var conteudo = "Novo Evento Adverso cadastrado:<br />";
            conteudo += $"Iniciais do Paciente: {paciente.inpac}<br />";
            conteudo += $"Nome do Investigador: {investigador.Nome}<br />";
            conteudo += $"Data da Randomização: {randomizacao.RandomizacaoData.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}<br />";
            conteudo += $"Data do Preenchimento: {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}";

            objEmail.Body = conteudo;

            EnviarEmail(objEmail);
        }

private static void EnviarEmail(MailMessage objEmail)
        {
            var objSmtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
                EnableSsl = true,
                Port = 587
            };

            const string user = "####@#####.com.br";
            const string senha = "######";

            objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, senha);
            objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
        }
```

Comment: Em um outro comentário excluído você disse algo como passar por connectionstring, não entendi o que você estava pensando

Comment: @GabrielColetta tipo, fazer alguma verificação puxando na connectionstring, por eu ter 2 ambientes, eu tenho 2 connectionstring no sistema, ai nesse caso, verificar qual estar sendo usada, ou verificar a url entende? eu tenho um exemplo aqui que verifica pea URL, só que não estou conseguindo adaptalo para utilizar no meu MailService. ---

var isHomolog = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("homolog") || Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("localhost") ? true : false;

Comment: O que posso te recomendar é fazer uma tag no web.config falando se é desenvolvimento ou produção, no caso do Deploy do sistema ele trocaria o web.config corretamente.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia colocar uma flag no seu web.config, por exemplo:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ambiente" value="Produção" />
</appSettings>
```

E para acessar ele, você usaria:

```
var ambiente = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambiente"];
```

No caso do `web.Debug.config` você usaria como `"Desenvolvimento"`, e no `web.Release.config` utilizaria `"Produção"`, assim quando você fazer deploy ele faria transformaria seu web.config com o ambiente correto.

Se o ambiente for Asp.Net Core, a propria API possui uma flag que indica se você esta em desenvolvimento:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        //DESENVOLVIMENTO.
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar utilizar aqui Gabriel, muito obrigado